# Generate Star Dynamically through jquery/Javascript/asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I know this is simple and easy. I have a repeater and it contains the data like

```
  **Name**          **Rating**
    Abc                  3.5
    Def                  4
    GHI                  3
    JKL                  4.5
```

and I am trying to generate star in place of `Rating` I have a code like this

```
      <asp:Repeater ID="MovieRatingRepeater" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
          <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.SourceName")%>&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <label id="MovieRatinglabel">
             <div id="RatingMovie" data-score="<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Rating")%>"></div>
             </label>
               </div>
         </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

In code behind I have done this

```
      MovieRatingRepeater.DataSource = objYPCategoryMasterDataAccess.GetMoviesRatingDetails(Int64.Parse(drv.Row[6].ToString()));
            MovieRatingRepeater.DataBind();
```

which contains the data which is already mentioned above.
I have tried this code but it doesnt works

```
     $('[id$=RatingMovie]').raty({
            score: function () {
                return $(this).attr('data-score');
            }
        });
```

I found that the .raty() is not a function error. Any solution to show star in place of number through jquery or asp.net control or by using javascript

Comment: Can you provide the rendered HTML, then we might help you with the script

Comment: I have edited some portion of the question please refer to it

Comment: Did you include [jQuery raty](http://wbotelhos.com/raty/) plugin? Also, ids must be unique; you are using same id in a repeater control.

Comment: I have used that but firebug shows an error